# How To Iterate over Rows to Create Groups

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, grouping

I have a table in this form:

```
User | Time_stamp | Group
1    | 12:00:00   | NewGroup
1    | 15:00:00   | NewGroup
2    | 13:00:00   | NewGroup
2    | 14:00:00   | OverlapsPreviousGroup
3    | 13:00:00   | NewGroup
3    | 14:00:00   | OverlapsPreviousGroup
3    | 15:00:00   | OverlapsPreviousGroup
3    | 16:00:00   | OverlapsPreviousGroup
3    | 18:00:00   | NewGroup
3    | 19:00:00   | OverlapsPreviousGroup
4    | 14:00:00   | NewGroup
```

and would like to create a column that creates groups for each user based on the value "NewGroup", e.g.

```
User | Time_stamp | Group                 | UserGroup
1    | 12:00:00   | NewGroup              | 1
1    | 15:00:00   | NewGroup              | 2
2    | 13:00:00   | NewGroup              | 1
2    | 14:00:00   | OverlapsPreviousGroup | 1
2    | 20:00:00   | NewGroup              | 2
3    | 13:00:00   | NewGroup              | 1
3    | 14:00:00   | OverlapsPreviousGroup | 1
3    | 15:00:00   | OverlapsPreviousGroup | 1
3    | 16:00:00   | OverlapsPreviousGroup | 1
3    | 18:00:00   | NewGroup              | 2
3    | 19:00:00   | OverlapsPreviousGroup | 2
4    | 14:00:00   | NewGroup              | 1
```

i.e. for each user every time the value "NewGroup" is seen the UserGroup value increments by 1, otherwise it takes the same value as the previous row. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You want a cumulative sum of counts of NewGroup.  Use `countif()` as a window function:

```
select t.*,
       countif(group = 'NewGroup') over (partition by user order by time_stamp) as usergroup
from t;
```